# How to move a node element to be the first inside its parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div onload='this.parentNode.prependChild();'>A</div>
</div>
```

I tried to move the `<div>A</div>` to the top of all child elements with inline script but didn't work with `prependChild()`, What is my mistake?

Comment: there is no load event on a `<div>`

Comment: @charlietfl isn't it considered a loaded element if it  came from an AJAX request?

Comment: Did you mean [`parentNode.prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) rather than `prependChild()`? Also, can you show your ajax code?

Comment: @Toleo no, the dom doesn't have any special ajax related events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only attach the onload event handler to the body element. However, it is fairly simple to move the last child to be the first within its parent:

```js
$('#parent').prepend($('#parent > div:last-child'))
```

```html
down vote
favorite
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript in the head section and have a window.onload over there. The following will place the element first in your parent div.
This is vanilla javascript. Which will work even with jQuery... Your choice!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  var elem = document.getElementById("thisone");
  parent.prepend(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div id="thisone">A</div>
</div>
```